# How to replace multiple space to single space in string (java)?

Tags: java, string, character

What i want to do is to replace multiple space to single space in a string.

I have string variable

```
String text = "i  want  to  replace   multiple space";
```

and i want it change into

```
String text = "i want to replace multiple space";
```

how can i do it?, help me please, thanks before.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: This was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958955/how-to-remove-duplicate-white-spaces-in-string-using-java)

Answer (score 3):

With regex
try

```
"my   extra spaced   string".replaceAll("\\s+?"," ");
```

thats preatty it.

Comment: This is not correct. It should be `"my   extra spaced   string".replaceAll("\\s+"," ")`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
   text = text.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
```

Comment: and how to replace multiple space in text file line by line?

Comment: you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039980/java-replace-line-in-text-file and then use the answer from this question to do the replacing.