# "Removing" Duplicate spaces from a char array java

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I'm attempting to create a method which will take a char array, cut out any duplicate spaces (2 or more) and then place `'\u0000'` characters at the end for however many spaces were cut out so that the array length is satisfied. I realize I have to shift the elements down but this is where I'm having trouble. My program works fine with 2 spaces but a sequence of three in a row will throw it off. I understand why this is happening but I don't know how to fix it. I know it stems from the code `characters[j] = characters[j+1]` but I don't know how to go about fixing it.

```
int duplicateCount = 0;
// Create a loop to read the element values
for(int i = 0; i + 1 < characters.length; i++){
    // If the element is a space and the next one is a space
    if(characters[i] == ' ' && characters[i+1] == ' '){
        // Add to duplicate count and start shifting values down
        duplicateCount++;
        // *THIS IS WHERE I THINK BUG IS*
        for(int j = i; j < characters.length - 1; j++){
            characters[j] = characters[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
    // Replace characters at end with how many duplicates were found
    for(int replace = characters.length - duplicateCount; replace < characters.length; replace++){
        characters[replace] = '\u0000';
    }
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958955/how-to-remove-duplicate-white-spaces-in-string-using-java/3958979#3958979

Comment: Does this work with chars? And on top of that, arrays? It seems it only applies to strings

Comment: You want all the spaces to be moved to the end. right?

Comment: Correct, all spaces will go to the end as \u0000 characters

Comment: Did your problem get solved?

Comment: I think the question was a bit misunderstood here. Probably partly my fault for not explaining enough. However, I was able to solve it in another thread. :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want all the spaces to be removed from between non-space characters and add \u0000 to the end.

If that's the issue, try this  out:
I have used `loops` and `if` statements to achieve it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        int j =i+1;
        if (characters[i] == ' ' || characters[i] == '\u0000' ) {
            while (j<characters.length && (characters[j] == ' ' || characters[j] == '\u0000')) {

                j++;  //increment j till a non-space char is found

            }
            if(j<characters.length && (characters[j] != ' ' || characters[j] != '\u0000')) 
                // to ensure that the control entered while
            {
           characters[i] = characters[j];   //swapping the values
            characters[j] = '\u0000';    //giving value \u0000 to position j
        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because you answer is more helpful and simple way, so +1 uv

Comment: @PiyushGupta You shouldn't have deleted that. Should have made appropriate corrections. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution if you want to keep your current code.
Just add 1 line i--.

```
int duplicateCount = 0;
// Create a loop to read the element values
for(int i = 0; i + 1 < characters.length; i++){
    // If the element is a space and the next one is a space
    if(characters[i] == ' ' && characters[i+1] == ' '){
        // Add to duplicate count and start shifting values down
        duplicateCount++;
        // *THIS IS WHERE I THINK BUG IS*
        for(int j = i; j < characters.length - 1; j++){
            characters[j] = characters[j+1];
            }
         i--; // so that multiple space case can be handled
        }
    }
    // Replace characters at end with how many duplicates were found
    for(int replace = characters.length - duplicateCount; replace < characters.length; replace++){
        characters[replace] = '\u0000';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count = 0;  // Count of non-space elements

    // Traverse the array. If element encountered is
    // non-space, then replace the element at index 'count'
    // with this element
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] != '')
            arr[count++] = arr[i]; // here count is
                                   // incremented

    // Now all non-space elements have been shifted to
    // Make all elements '\u0000' from count to end.
    while (count < n)
        arr[count++] = 0;
```