# How to remove String Empty space in android

Tags: android, string

I want to remove empty space from the first String and make it look like the second String.

```
1)EVANS MD                 JOSEPH       J
2)EVANS MD JOSEPH J
```

My code:

```
String finaloriginAutoCompleteText = providerOriginAddress.get(position).getProviderName();
```

Comment: finaloriginAutoCompleteText.trim();

explanation: It returns a copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space.

Comment: no that's not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate white spaces in string using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958955/how-to-remove-duplicate-white-spaces-in-string-using-java)

Comment: @Ram This only works with whitespaces at the beginning and end, trim() will not remove inner extra whitespaces [String.trim()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String finaloriginAutoCompleteText;
finaloriginAutoCompleteText = providerOriginAddress.get(position).getProviderName();

// trim the string (for leading and ending whitespaces) and then
// replace all remaining (inner) multiple spaces (\s+) with a single space (" ")
finaloriginAutoCompleteText = finaloriginAutoCompleteText.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Comment: so how can we remove with whitespaces at the beginning and end and also how to remove inner extra whitespaces