# Java String trim has no effect

Tags: java, string, unicode, trim, spaces

Java String trim is not removing a whitespace character for me.

```
String rank = (some method);
System.out.println("(" + rank + ")");
```

The output is `(1  )`.  Notice the space to the right of the 1.

I have to remove the trailing space from the string `rank` but neither `rank.trim()` nor `rank.replace(" ","")` removes it.

The string `rank` just remains the same either way.

**Edit: Full Code:**:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.4icu.org/ca/").timeout(1000000).get();
Element table = doc.select("table").get(7);
Elements rows = table.select("tr");
for (Element row: rows) {
  String rank = row.select("span").first().text().trim();
  System.out.println("("+rank+")");
}
```

Why can't I remove that space?

Comment: Do you use `rank = rank.trim();` or just `rank.trim();`? The second one won't work.

Comment: provide trim() code that you have used ..

Comment: @TerryLi Maybe you should give us an idea what `(some method)` does.

Comment: @Baz `(some method)` just tries to extract the ranking for each university from this site:http://www.4icu.org/ca/

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You haven't provided enough information at the moment.

Comment: You're asking a question about `trim()` which doesn't work. And the code you show doesn't contain any call to the `trim()` method. Show us the relevant code.

Comment: i dont know why while running your code giving me NPE ...

Comment: @TerryLi: That's still not a short but complete program, is it?

Comment: @TerryLi NullpointerException figured out its in row.select("span").first().text().trim()

Comment: @JonSkeet its almost working short code having NPE that i have commented where..

Comment: @HarmeetSingh The first two rows don't work. I didn't provide complete code.

Comment: @TerryLi you should have provided proper code..

Comment: @JonSkeet It's not complete enough. I just omitted the code that removes the first two rows from the loop.

Comment: @TerryLi: As you say, it's *not* complete enough. A short but complete program should allow an answerer to copy the code into a text editor, compile it, run it, and see the problem immediately - without the code doing anything unrelated to the problem. As the person asking for help, it's up to you to do enough work to help others help you. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The source code of that website shows the special html character `&nbsp;`. Try searching or replacing the following in your java String: `\u00A0`.

That's a non-breakable space. See: [I have a string with "\u00a0", and I need to replace it with "" str_replace fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592502/i-have-string-with-u00a0-and-i-need-to-replace-it-with-str-replace-fails)

```
rank = rank.replaceAll("\u00A0", "");
```

should work. Maybe add a double `\\` instead of the `\`.

Comment: @TerryLi See, if you supply sufficient information, we are able to help you. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Worth noting this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437933/how-to-properly-trim-whitespaces-from-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 8):

You should assign the result of trim back to the `String` variable. Otherwise it is not going to work, because strings in Java are *immutable*.

```
String orig = "    quick brown fox    ";
String trimmed = original.trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

The character is a non-breaking space, and is thus not removed by the `trim()` method. Iterate through the characters and print the int value of each one, to know which character you must replace by an empty string to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Are you assigning the String?

```
String rank = " blabla "; 
rank = rank.trim();
```

Don't forget the second assignment, or your trimmed string will go nowhere.

You can look this sort of stuff up in the API as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

As you can see this method returns a String, like most methods that operate on a String do. They return the modified String and leave the original String in tact.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and did little manipulation on java's trim() method.
You can use this code to trim:

```
public static String trimAdvanced(String value) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(value);

        int strLength = value.length();
        int len = value.length();
        int st = 0;
        char[] val = value.toCharArray();

        if (strLength == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ') || (val[st] == '\u00A0')) {
            st++;
            if (st == strLength) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ') || (val[len - 1] == '\u00A0')) {
            len--;
            if (len == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }


        return (st > len) ? "" : ((st > 0) || (len < strLength)) ? value.substring(st, len) : value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim function returns a new copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

```
rank = rank.trim();// This will remove and save rank without leading and trailing spaces
```

will give the result you want.

Replace method will not work if you pass empty string for replacement.

Comment: If you are not sure about spaces i will suggest you to use regex to extract the number. Use "((-|\\+)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)+" regex will extract number form string.

Comment: I'll take you advice. But I still wonder what the two spaces denote.

Comment: @TerryLi Unless you give us more information (like a small working program), we will never know...

Answer (score 0):

Since String in java are immutable ie they cannot be changed. You need to reassign it to some temporary string. And then using that string you can convert it into int.

```
String temp=rank.trim()
int te= Integer.parseInt(temp)
```