# How to remove white space remove in list object?

Tags: java, string, dom

i want output of my java program without whitespaces ,
my code is -

```
Source source1=new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString1));
List<Element> temp1 = source1.getElementById("main").getAllElementsByClass("grid_3 alpha");

                String line = temp1.toString();
                String temps = line.trim();//using this
                            String temps = line.replaceAll("\\s+","")// or this
                if(!temps.isEmpty())
                {
                sendResponse(resp, "Information for:"+searchWord+":" +temps);
                }
```

When i am using **Trim** it gives output  with lot of space between Information and 
SATISH

```
Information for::[




SATISH


JHOTWARA (JAIPUR)

Party:CPI
S/o|D/o|W/o: Om Prakash
Age: 42
```

When i am using `String temps = line.replaceAll("\\s+","")`;

it gives output as:

```
Information for::[<divclass="grid_3alpha"style='background:khaki;'><h2class="main-title">SatishKumar<fontcolor=greensize=1>(Winner)
ELECTEDFROMBIHARLEGISLATIVEASSEMBLY
<divclass="grid_2alpha">Party:JD(U)<divclass="grid_2alpha">S/o|D/o|W/o:JagdishPrasad<divclass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String temps = line.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
```

will leave one space per run of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Trim will only cut leading and trailing whitspaces see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198875/how-many-spaces-will-java-string-trim-remove).
I did the same like you want to, I used simply

```
String temps = line.replaceAll(" ","");
```